# How to check if a user is a Salesforce Administrator

Tags: rest-api

Using the REST API, what is the best way to check if a specific user is a SFDC Administrator, given his Id?

Comment: You want to check if they have a specific profile?

Comment: @DanielBallinger Not exactly. I would like to check if they have admin privileges.

Comment: If you're not satisfied with profile, what combination of system permissions defines an "admin" to you ? It may be good to clarify these things in your question with an edit/update.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke I'm not quite familiar with the various system permissions. I'm looking for a way to understand if the user is some kind of a power user in his org. Is there some combination of permissions that is usually configured for power users in SFDC?

Comment: I think  You should look for user profile . all users' powers and permissions are configured in profile.  Profile can tell u what a user can do or can't do .